# Array formatting into a specific format?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am getting an array like below after i formatted my result set into the below format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxx@2456
    [1] => xxx@2345
    [2] => xxy@1234
    [3] => xxy@123
    [4] => xyz@3456
);
```

I want the result array from the above array like below. I am thinking how ot proceed using PHP string functions or is there any other way.

Note: There may be so many array elements like the above but i want unique elements after we added last digits after '@'.

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  xxx@4801
    [1] =>  xxy@1464
    [2] =>  xyz@3456
);
```

Any ideas how to proceed....... In the above output array format xxx@4801 is sum of 2345 and 2456 of Input array.......

Comment: Where did you get `xxx@4801` ???? Where is the original array before format ????

Comment: xxx is all array elements.........i made it like a string by using concatenation.

Comment: Its confusing ... can you update your question with proper relative examples

Comment: Hey just an array is in that format..........tell me is there any way to get into the second format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$unique = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    $c = explode("@", $b);
    if (isset($a[$c[0]])) {
        $d = explode("@", $a[$c[0]]);
        $a[$c[0]] = $c[0] . "@" . ($c[1] + $d[1]);
    } else {
        $a[$c[0]] = $b;
    }
    return $a;
}, array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($unique));
```

[Output](http://eval.in/5748)

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxx@4801
    [1] => xxy@1357
    [2] => xyz@3456
)
```

[Simple Online Demo](http://eval.in/5748)

Comment: this gives just gives unique values......i want unique rows by adding the contents after '@'..........

Comment: Check my output once.....your output gives xxx@2345 but i want xxx@4801........where 4801 is sum of 2345 and 2456

Comment: that is why i asked you to make your question clear ..... i would update answer with solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_unique()` function and reindex it with `array_values()` Find the code for example.

- [`array_unique($array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [`array_values(array_unique($array));`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: hey lalith can you check the answer given by Baba.............In that what is function($a,$b).....

Comment: I dint check the edits you've done recently, I've answered before baba , so guess the reduce and explode helped you out.

Comment: what is that function($a,$b)

Comment: array_reduce() can have a callable function($a,$b) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php